# Добавление/удаление классов при полноэкранном скролле

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть страница, на ней поэкранный скролл, а это значит что дефолтный скролл отключен. Поэтому функция window.scrollTop(), которую можно было применить для добавления/удаления классов при скролле до определенного места на странице не работает. Раздел сейчас при любой высоте экрана вытягивается на 100%, соотсветственно точной высоты каждой секции нету. Как можно добавлять и убирать классы при скролле до конкретной секции? Если кто-то знает, напишите пожалуйста пример кода

Comment: Было бы хорошо узнать, как именно блокируется стандартный скрол. Потому что именно там кроется решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: @alexoander Спасибо, я уже нашел решение в функционале самого плагина

Comment: ,поделитесь ответом с нами! Напишите ответ и пометьте его как ответ. Просто мне тоже интересно =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовался плагин fullpage.js; В события afterload или onleave можно забить условия, в которых писать сколько угодно js кода. Лучшим вариантом является afterload, хотя дело вкуса. В документации, кстати говоря, всё это написано с примерами, так что не ленимся читать readme)

Answer (score 2):

Можно создать переменную `scrollTop` и при скроллинге прибавлять/убавлять значение . А высота каждого блока это `window.innerHeight`.

Comment: Скроллинга как такового нету. Просто при прокрутке колеса происходит трансформация по вертикали. Посчитать расстояние scrollTop() невозможно, так что ответ вообще мимо.

Comment: Ну есть же функция которая отвечает за трансформацию, ну вот в неё добавляете переменную и при прокрутке колеса вверх или вниз прибавляете или убавляете значение соответсвенно.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],

    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
        var loadedSection = $(this);

        //using index
        if(index == 3){
            alert("Section 3 ended loading");
        }

        //using anchorLink
        if(anchorLink == 'secondSlide'){
            alert("Section 2 ended loading");
        }
    }
});
```

Использовался плагин fullpage.js, вот таким кодом можно прописать любые изменения при перелистывании слайдов